# Creating custom database table with crud operation

Tags: customization, table

I am new to wordpress. I going to work on one project that is having 400 pages. Out of that only 3-4 pages are the dynamic pages and rest are the static pages.

What I meant to say by this, most of the pages our of 400 pages are CMS pages those cab be managed by the wordpress admin CMS editor. However some pages are there where students will do registration and then can select specific course among the various courses by providing some information and based on that courses will get filtered out. This like easily achievable by core PHP, normally we do for regular projects.

In short words, I want to ask there is there any way that we can put our own normal php pages that can show a form, can perform normal form submit, js call, table listing and all this with non wp_ tables. Some pages in wordpress framework that work as stand alon custom php page ( nothing to deal with wordpress structure ) and some other pages which work well with wordpress.

I am planning to use wordpress for it. This pages will have functionalities like normal crud operation.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've edited question and provided more information. Thank you.

Comment: What is your specific issue, where are you stuck. Your question is really broad, it really has the feel of asking for a complete project. Please see [ask] and [help] on some guidelines on how to ask a good question

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've added yet more details. Sorry but I am not asking about project, I am asking about approach, or choosing wordpress is right. Would appreciate your time. Thank you.